# Identify when default Android Checkbox animation ends

Tags: android, animation, checkbox, material-design

When clicking on a Checkbox, a default Android material design animation is triggered (from blank to a "V" mark, and from "V" mark to a blank).

I want to identify when the animation ends.

According to documentation, this should be possible in one of two ways -

- When the checkbox is checked or unchecked (`setOnCheckedChangeListener()`), obtain the current Animation object (`getAnimation()`) and register a listener on it (`setAnimationListener()`). Unfortunately, this doesn't work - the Animation object, at this point in time, is `null`.
- Subclass the Checkbox object and implement its `onAnimationEnd()` method. Unfortunately, this doesn't work as well - the method is never called.

What am I missing? What is a good way to identify when such a default animation ends? I assume the relevant events can be registered on some other view in the activity, but I can't figure out which.

Here is a relevant code snippet for the first approach (animation is always `null`) -

```
    CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkbox1);
    checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
            Animation animation = compoundButton.getAnimation();
            Log.d("Checkbox", "Animation is " + animation);
       }
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

I was somewhat successful setting the following OnCheckedChangeListener on the Checkbox.

```
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    Drawable drawable = buttonView.getButtonDrawable().getCurrent();
    if (drawable instanceof AnimatedVectorDrawable) {
        AnimatedVectorDrawable animatedDrawable = (AnimatedVectorDrawable) drawable;
        animatedDrawable.registerAnimationCallback(new Animatable2.AnimationCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Drawable drawable) {
                super.onAnimationEnd(drawable);
                // your action goes here
            }
        });
    } else {
        // and maybe here as well as a fallback
    }
}
```

Quite often (maybe 50% of the time) the `onAnimationEnd` callback is triggered twice. I don’t understand why, though.

Comment: onAnimationEnd callback is triggered twice, I'm guessing that if it is a radio button, you're getting onCheckedChange for the uncheck of the first radio button, followed by the check of the second radio button.